# Create Android Service from React (with android native call)

Tags: android, multithreading, react-native, service

I have created a native package with a native module which extends "ReactContextBaseJavaModule". From here i can create methods inside this package and call them from react native.

What i want is that inside this module i can create a method which creates an Android Service passing some arguments, then the Service will create a thread with the passing argument , do stuff and return the result to javascript. By far i have

```
public class ServiceCreatorModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
public static final String REACT_CLASS = "ServiceCreator";
private static ReactApplicationContext reactContext = null;
private TimerService MyTimerService;

public ServiceCreatorModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
    // Pass in the context to the constructor and save it so you can emit events
    // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#the-toast-module
    super(context);

    reactContext = context;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    // Tell React the name of the module
    // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#the-toast-module
    return REACT_CLASS;
}

@Override
public Map<String, Object> getConstants() {
    // Export any constants to be used in your native module
    // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#the-toast-module
    final Map<String, Object> constants = new HashMap<>();
    constants.put("EXAMPLE_CONSTANT", "sincronizzato ;)");

    return constants;
}

@ReactMethod
public void exampleMethod () {
    // An example native method that you will expose to React
    // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#the-toast-module
    final WritableMap event = Arguments.createMap();
    event.putString("greeting", "ciaoooo");
    emitDeviceEvent("EXAMPLE_EVENT", event);
}

@ReactMethod
public void createTimer() {
   /* for (int i = 0; i < 55; i++) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        WritableMap event = Arguments.createMap();
        event.putInt("timer", i);
        emitDeviceEvent("TIMER_UPDATED", event);
    }*/
    MyTimerService = new TimerService();
    startService(new Intent(ServiceCreatorModule.this, TimerService.class));
    doBindService();
}


private static void emitDeviceEvent(String eventName, @Nullable WritableMap eventData) {
    // A method for emitting from the native side to JS
    // https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#sending-events-to-javascript
    reactContext.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit(eventName, eventData);
}
```

}

From here i want to call createTimer method which will start "MyTimerService" that is this class :

```
public class TimerService extends Service {
private Looper mServiceLooper;
private final IBinder binder = new ServiceBinder();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // To avoid cpu-blocking, we create a background handler to run our service
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("TutorialService",
            Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    // start the new handler thread
    thread.start();

    mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
    // start the service using the background handler
    mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Thread thread = new Thread(new MyThreadClass(startId));
    thread.start();

    return START_STICKY;
}

protected void makeCounter(){

}


@Override
public IBinder onBind( Intent intent ) {

    return binder;
} public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {

    public TimerService getService() {

        return TimerService.this;
    }
}
```

}

Problem is that `startService(new Intent(ServiceCreatorModule.this, TimerService.class));
        doBindService();` will fire an error.

Then the other problem is that i should emit and event to pass back data to react native and i can do that only with a reactContext ( which i have on the ServiceCreatorModule but not inside the Service itselves ( that's why i need to pass something to it )

Anyone?